# How to make application run from python code Raspbian

Tags: raspbian, python

I have made 2 games, one is pong (using Pygame), and the other one is a text-based quiz. These codes I have made using Python 2.7.1 on Windows laptop. My question is how can I run it on the Pi (which is running Raspbian Wheezy) as an application or from a software which runs Python files. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest way to run the program is by typing `python mygame.py`

If you want to be able to run the program by double clicking on it, or by just typing the filename, it's a little different than in Windows. The file needs to be executable, and have a shebang.

To make a file executable you'll need to do 2 things:

1. Add a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) to the top of your program's main file.  This tells your OS how to interpret a seemingly random collection of text. In python, the appropriate shebang is `#!/usr/bin/env python`
2. Tell the OS that it's okay to run the file as an executable `chmod +x mygame.py`

If you have a colored terminal, typing `ls -l` should now show the filename in green.

It's also worth noting that linux permissions are a little different than in Windows.  Using the same `ls -l` command above, you should see a file owner and group.  You'll want to make sure that the owner and group match your user.  If it doesn't you can change it with the command `sudo chown pi:pi mygame.py` (assuming your user is named pi).